# Python - managing large data

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.4, large-data

I'm working on an application using Python (3.4) and PyQt. The goal of the program is to manage and analyze large amount of data - up to ~50 binary files, which might be of total size up to 2-3 GB. When I tried to load a couple files into the program, it stops responding during loading and then takes ~1.5GB RAM just to keep running. My question is quite general - what are the possible methods in python/PyQt for handling such data sets?

Comment: This is impossible to answer. Only a very general suggestion: decompose your program, and create a computational kernel without any (Py)Qt that does the processing of your 50 files. Let it run, see how it behaves, optimise. Then, hook it into your gui-app. Also, with these process sizes, make sure you use 64 bit python.

Comment: No, I appreciate the comment. I'm not looking for a "fix" or something, just some suggestions to consider and try to implement, so thank you

Comment: Assuming the files are uncompressed, the amount of disk space and the amount of memory will be similar for efficient binary representations. What sort of analysis are you doing, and how are you loading the files? Most analysis can be done in a streaming fashion. One option would be to load one file at a time and extract the information you need for aggregation, only keeping that in memory.

Comment: I think that this is a very board cuestion, How you are opening this data? what kind of a analysis need to do? how are you visualizing the data?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The only thing that comes to mind is that you can load part of the files at a time...

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the HDF5 format, which can access using **h5py**, **pytables**, or other python packages.  Depending on the dataformat, HDF5 could enable you to access the data on the HD in an efficient manner, which in practice means that you can save memory.  The downside is that it requires some effort on your side as a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

@deets got it right... decompose the problem.

The question is very broad... as it does not describe the downstream needs.   So let me share the framework I've had to build to work with ... the key solution was using HDF and building some services around the data structures in the bulkstore... it has given me a nice solution.

My app is divided into

```
 a) remote sources -> Collection Subsystem  -> Bulkstore
 b) Bulkstore      -> BatchAnalysis         -> dyanmicstore
 c) dynamicstore   -> webapp+visualization  -> UI
```

The collection system is continuously collecting logs from across 30+ languages, parsing the XML and appending rows into a single bulkstore language HDF5 file.

The size of the bulkstore varies by language ... from 20G to <1M...

The batchanalysis  (@deets 'computational kernel') is designed to use the latest ~12M events (memory bound).

The key is to learn how to structure the bulkstore... in my case I divide the bulkstore into quarters with a master look aside index across all quarters.    The services are divided into the following class hierarchy:

```
bulkstore  (core HDF services)
+- dataset   (manage datasets/directory within HDF)
   +- appdata     (my apps knowledge of logs across the datasets)
      +- dynamicstore   (output of batchanalysis are HDF's themselves)
```

Hope this helps...

1 tip... there is a trick for managing datasets within a HDF... ie. HDF's with large data takes a LONG time just to get the directory of datasets .

If you need to process the  interested in building a Spark solution for the BatchAnalysis...